# I want to know why this program below is not working i want to print the reverse of each string?

Tags: arrays, c, string, sorting, reverse

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char str[5][10];
    int i,j,k;
    printf("Enter 5 strings:");
    for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
    {
        scanf("%s",str[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;str[i][j]!='\0';j++);
        for(k=j-1;k>=0;k--)
        {
            printf("%s",str[i][k]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

please also explain my mistake and how to make such program without strrev() function i know it might be a dumb question but i am asking this because i am new to programming please help.

Comment: What is your exact input? What is the exact output you expect? What is the exact output you actually get? Have you tried with a simpler program, where you do it using only a single hard-coded string? Have you tried to *debug* your program? And if your compiler doesn't give you warnings, then you should consider enabling more warnings, and treat them as errors that must be fixed.

Comment: Also please read (or refresh) [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Be careful, your `str` can contain words of only 9 `char`s plus `\0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you were trying to do?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char str[5][10];
    int i,j,k;
    printf("Enter 5 strings:");
    for(i=0;i<5;++i)
    {
        scanf("%s",str[i]);
    }
    
    for(i=0; i<5; ++i)
    {
        for(j=strlen(str[i])-1; j>=0; --j)
        {
            printf("%c", str[i][j]);
        }
        printf(" ");
    }
    
 
 return 0;   
}
```

---

```
Enter 5 strings: Hello world this might work

Output:

olleH dlrow siht thgim krow
```

Comment: This still has the issue that `str` can contain words of only 9 `char`s.

Comment: You should really try to explain what changes you made to the code, and why you made those changes.

Answer (score 1):

`%s` is for passing `char*` and printing a string. You should use `%c` to pass `int` and print one character via `printf()`.

In other words, you should use

```
printf("%c",str[i][k]);
```

or

```
putchar(str[i][k]);
```

instead of

```
printf("%s",str[i][k]);
```